# How would print a PSObject without headers?

Tags: powershell, formatting

I have this script that runs (it gets a current Microsoft Version), and would like it to print without headers.

This is the working script:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "Microsoft Office*" -and $_.PSChildName -notlike "{*"} | Select-Object DisplayName,  DisplayVersion | ForEach-Object {
[pscustomobject]@{
        Name =  ($_.DisplayName)
        Version=($_.DisplayVersion)
    }
}
```

I know usually,

```
gci | ft -HideTableHeaders
```

works, but how would I apply something like this within the PS-Object output.

Comment: I'd first save to a variable and then pipe to `|Format-Table -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders` eventually followed by `|Out-String -Width 300` or `|Out-File x:\path\file.txt -Width 300`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to override the `ToString()` method:

```
$customObject = [pscustomobject]@{
    Name =  ($_.DisplayName)
    Version=($_.DisplayVersion)
} |Add-Member -Name ToString -MemberType ScriptMethod -Value { 'Name: {0}, Version: {1}' -f $this.Name,$this.Version } -Force -Passthru
```

Now, when passed to a function that takes a string argument, it'll show up with your custom formatting:

```
function Add-LogEntry
{
  param([string]$Message)

  # write $message to event log or log file here
}

Add-LogEntry $customObject
```

Answer (score 0):

Piping to `Format-Table` (aliased to `ft`) is the intended way of accomplishing your task. Therefore, there is no way to remove the header within the `PSObject` without the assistance of an output formatter, or `Format-Table`. Using anything else, such as using the `.ToString()` would only be a waste of time because `Format-Table` was built to, well, format tables.